# Add an IF to an arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple one that is driving me nuts.
I have a long list of NPS scores and I need to create a new column and add the following formula.

```
=if(A3<=6,"Detractor",if(A3>=9,"Promoter","Neutral"))
```

It works great if I drag to the bottom but I can't always do that and need to use an arrayformula but I'm pulling out what hair I have left trying to make it work :(

Comment: Can you share an example of your sheet showing what is the end result you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your single cell to an array of cells

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A3:A)>0,(IF(A3:A<=6,"Detractor",IF(A3:A>=9,"Promoter","Neutral"))),""))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A<=6, "Detractor", IF(A3:A>=9, "Promoter", "Neutral")))
```

or advanced:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",, IF(A3:A<=6, "Detractor", IF(A3:A>=9, "Promoter", "Neutral"))))
```